# rails 4 - using cache with redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I'm trying to create GET URL that returns a resource located under 'public' folder, and i'm trying to use cache, to save redirects to the resource if not needed.
I have a table: 'ResourcesTable', that stores when was the last time that the resource was modified.

My route for the requested URL navigates to the controller that executes:

```
def handle_resource
    resource_path = params(:resource)
    last_updated_at = ResourcesTable.get_resource_timestamp(resource_path)
    if stale?(:last_modified => last_updated_at.utc) then
        redirect_to resource_path
```

The problem is, that its always goes to the 'redirect_to'.
I've checked with cURL, and the last_modify element in the header is the same as 'last_updated_at' returned from the DB.

Does anyone can help to make sure that it will do only one time the 'redirect_to', and takes the resource from cache the next time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question.

In cURL - we should insert the date of the HTTP request:

```
 curl -z 'Sun, 06 Nov 2024 08:49:37 GMT' -k -I -X GET URL_PATH
```

and that is how I can see when the 'stale?' method returns true or not.

In addition - 
The controller should not return any message in case that 'stale?' returns False.